# Car insurance in France for 100 days

Tags: france, automobiles, insurance

We are travelling to France for an extended stay which is over 90 days (~100). Our motor insurance only covers for 90 days out of UK and have told us they cannot extend this period. Could I cancel this policy after 30 days abroad and set up a new policy with another company to start while we are away and reset the 90 day period? Any other solutions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to subscribe an ad hoc insurance in your home country? I imagine it would be easier to file a claim from the UK with a UK company rather than having to do this over the phone with a French company.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion it would be smarter on your part to subscribe an ad hoc insurance in your home country. I imagine it would be easier to file a claim from the UK with a UK company rather than having to do this over the phone with a French company. To this purpose you should look for European car insurance, which extends the basic insurance cover - the minimum needed to drive legally in Europe - which should be included by default in your preexisting UK instance contract.

A quick search on a comparison website might come in handy here. A random query on Google revealed [this company which seems to provide a policy with annual foreign use included](https://www.stuartcollins.com/).